# Autoreconf error: failed with exit status: 1

Tags: apt, software-installation, git, github, autoconf

I try to install `mp4fpsmod` on `Linux 4.19.104+ x86_64 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` in Colab. To reproduse please copypaste these three lines into a [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb) cell and hit `shift+enter`:

```
!git clone -qqq https://github.com/nu774/mp4fpsmod.git > /dev/null
!sudo apt-get update -y -qqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -y -qqq autoconf > /dev/null
!cd mp4fpsmod/ && ./bootstrap.sh && ./configure && make && strip mp4fpsmod && make install
```

The error in `./bootstrap.sh`:

```
Running autoreconf...
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: adding subdirectory mp4v2 to autoreconf
autoreconf: Entering directory `mp4v2'
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force 
autoreconf: configure.ac: creating directory autoaux
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
configure.ac:83: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend opening an issue (if there is not an existing one open regarding this) on the package's Github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Install `libtool`:

```
!sudo apt-get update -y -qqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -y -qqq autoconf libtool > /dev/null
```

Comment: A command without any explanation is not a good answer!

Comment: `libtool` added

Comment: Please explain the command options as well. Why `-qqq` and then send output to `dev/null`? why `--fix-missing`? Why `autoconf`?